# Shell Script : read the output to run the next command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to run this but still not getting the output. Don't know were I am wrong.
First the script should login to the server
2nd command is "`netstat -tulpun | grep -i port` (port & server list is in the same file)
3rd It may get 3 to 4 output here but I need only 25 PID output not the others

```
#!/bin/bash  
while read -r -u10 server port line  
do  
echo ========== server: "$server" port: "$port" ==========  
   ssh $line "netstat -tulpunt | grep -E \"\b$port\b\"" | awk '{print $7}' | grep '/' | awk -F '/' '{print $1}' | xargs -I % bash -c 'echo Port % && ps -ef | grep % && echo ' | grep -v grep  
done 10< demo
```

Updated required output:

=====
Server1
Port `1311`

```
root      8063  8062  0  2014 ?        00:08:06 /opt/dm_cd -run
```

=====
Server2
Port `1311`

```
root      6844  6843  0  2014 ?        00:20:22 /etc/bin/linux/ds -run
```

=====
Server3
Port `8000`

```
applmgr   1505  4215  0  2014 ?        00:05:44 /app/Apache/bin/httpd -d
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that messy command line to run in the remote host. Please, show the output of the netstat command which that messy command line has to parse and the expected output.

Comment: please check I have add the requested in the Question

Comment: Your regexp `\"\b$port\b\"` looks strange. Maybe you should change it to something like `":$port"` . Then it seems that there is no 7 columns in output. Have not tested further. Did you tested it step by step adding one pipe a time?

Comment: If I exclude "xargs -I % bash -c 'echo Port % && ps -ef | grep % && echo ' | grep -v grep" i  am getting the exact output. but then xagrs is not taking the PID which I am getting from the netstat ouput to run the PS command

Comment: And what is the input? I say your `xargs -I ...` will not get any input because everything was filtered earlier.

Comment: i tried giving ":$port" instead of \"\b$port\b\" nothing changed

Comment: I will explain what I want exactly, netstat will take the port from  the file & will give the PID. I want that PID in the ps -ef | grep -i PID done

Comment: No I will get the PID only, every thing is filterd except the PID

Comment: Break down the ssh command and construct it piece by piece, see where the output goes out the window.

Comment: I have checked it run out after the xargs command

Comment: The desired output is not enough. Please, provide an example of the output of `netstat -tulpunt`.

Comment: This question duplicates http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/179263/4667

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unwanted output lines are probably due to the needed PID appearing in other columns of the `ps -ef` output (PPID, CMD) or as part of another PID. Replace `ps -ef` by `ps -fp%` to rectify it.