# unable to read the output to run the next command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

when this script is executed I get the PID, now I want to read the output "PID" and run the next command in this way

```
ps -ef | grep -i PID  


while read -r -u10 server port line  
do  
 echo ==========  server: "$server" port: "$port"  ==========  
ssh -qn "$server" "netstat -tulpunt | grep -E ":$port "" | awk '{print $7}' | grep '/' | awk -F "/" '{print $1}'  
echo  
done 10< demo
```

Sample output

```
========== server: Server1   port: 1311 ==========  
8063  

========== server: Server2   port: 1311 ==========  

========== server: Server3    port: 8000 ==========  
1505  

========== server: Server4   port: 1311 ==========  
8122
```

Comment: Skynet can you do this.

Comment: ***Possible duplicate question***. Is this not the same question than [this other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959343/shell-script-read-the-output-to-run-the-next-command)?

Comment: This question duplicates http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/179263/4667

Comment: what is the next command and how you wanna execute it. A brief would be helpful to provide you solution.

Answer (score 0):

> now I want to read the output "PID"

We can assign the output to a variable.

```
PID=`ssh -qn "$server" "netstat -tulpunt | grep -E ":$port "" | awk '{print $7}' | grep '/' | awk -F "/" '{print $1}'`
```

If you still want to see it:

```
echo $PID
```

> and run the next command in this way
>
> ```
> ps -ef | grep -i PID
> ```

This is an often seen, but silly idiom. Better use

```
ps -fp$PID
```